# Issue with subquery - All expressions must have explicit name in teradata

Tags: teradata

Don't understand what is going wrong. Can someone please help with the below query. I am new to Teradata SQL

| account_id | trans_date_fnl | date (Currentdate) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-05-06 | 2021-06-03 |
| 12345 | 2021-05-29 | 2021-06-03 |
| 12346 | 2021-05-28 | 2021-06-03 |

SQL

```
SELECT TRANSDATE FROM
(
  SELECT TRANS_DATE_fnl, CURRENT_DATE, (CURRENT_DATE - TRANS_DATE_fnl) AS "TRANSDATE"
  FROM financial_db.fin_trans_puneet
  WHERE extract(year from TRANS_DATE_fnl) = '2021' AND extract(MONTH from TRANS_DATE_fnl) = '5'
  GROUP BY TRANS_DATE_fnl
) a
```

Error :-

> Executed as Single statement. Failed [3707 : 42000] Syntax error,
> expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an
> 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between ')' and ';'.   Elapsed time =
> 00:00:00.007

Output :-

I need to have the customer who have done transaction between 5 to 10 days along with the transaction date

Comment: Your query has multiple problems.  Please add sample input table data, and then also include the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have edited the comments with the details.

Comment: Hi Tim, It was my Bad, I have not given the explicit name to the system function current date column due to which it was showing error. Now the data is getting retrieved. Thanks alot Tim

Comment: Your query might run, but I doubt it returns the expected result. Based on your narration you need something llike `where TRANS_DATE_fnl between current_date-10 and current_date -5`